# Monogame + WP8.1 - Orientation resets after ApplyChanges

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, orientation, monogame

I am creating a small custom 2D game engine and I am stuck setting up the orientation for my game.
I would like to use only LandscapeRight, therefore I set the PageOrientation and SupportedOrientation in my GamePage.xaml and in my graphics' PresentationParams to LandscapeRight, but after calling ApplyChanges, the orientation resets back to Portrait.

I even tried setting the BackBuffer width/height, setting the PreferredBackBuffer width/height, and tried calling/not calling ApplyChanges in my Game constructor, Initialize, LoadContent, etc methods, but no change in the orientation.

Can someone advise me how to set up orientation properly? I dont need complex solutions, some pseudo code would be more than enough as my game engine is separated into many small dlls.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There must be some or other setting you're missing. I had no troubles doing this last night. I merely edited the orientation properties in GamePage.xaml and I was fine off. Check again, and if it still fails, show some code.

Comment: Yesterday, after a lot of google search, I found a codeplex discussion where someone said that maybe the 3.2.2 MonoGame installer has wrong wp8 template, but if I install the MonoGame libraries through NuGet, everything will be fine. Well, I am on it, though there were some issues with adding the binaries through NuGet, but I will post my result when I successfully install everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the issue:

MonoGame 3.2.2. installer has corrupted template, so I deleted the old project that was created from the template and targeted Windows Phone 8.1, then created a new project, added MonoGame 3.2.2. libraries through NuGet, copied the MonoGame.dll into an 'Externals' folder and referenced it in the engine's class libraries. After rebuild all, orientation worked like a charm! :)